# Can a Paladin of Slaughter/Tyranny heal themselves with Deadly Touch?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Per the text of Deadly Touch, other than being able to use it explicitly to harm the living and heal undead, it functions exactly as Lay on Hands. RAW would have me believe it could also heal living, as that is the original use of Lay on Hands, and this just adds more uses that fit the way these variants are supposed to work. My question is, can they heal themselves or other living party members with Deadly Touch, since it's still technically Lay on Hands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, unless the targets are undead.

> Deadly Touch (Su)
>
> Beginning at 2nd level, a paladin of slaughter can cause wounds with a successful touch attack. Each day she can deal a total number of hit points of damage equal to her paladin level x her Charisma bonus. An opponent subjected to this attack can make a Will save (DC 10 + 1/2 paladin level + paladin's Cha modifier) to halve the damage dealt.
>
> Alternatively, a paladin of slaughter can use any or all of this power to cure damage to undead creatures, just as an inflict wounds spell does. This power otherwise functions identically to the paladin's lay on hands ability.

To not repeat themselves saying again that is a touch, the hit points healed are Cha modifier x paladin level and you can control the amount you heal per use, they said that other than the fact that it heals undeads instead of living beings, it has the same limits and restrictions as lay on hands to healing living beings. That "otherwise" means exactly that it doesn't heal living beings, only undead creatures.

Answer (score 3):

No, not unless you pull of a trick.

The feat Tomb Tainted Soul (Libris Mortis: The Book of Undead, p. 31) allows you to heal from negative energy, but take damage from positive energy just like an undead would. The feat requires you to be nongood, but that's not an issue here.